# How to find a unique repeating group in regex

Tags: regex

My regular expression = `'(\d+)\1+'`
My Aim is to capture repeating patters such as 2323 , 1212, 345345 which have different digits. Current regex also captures 11,22,11111 which I need to exclude

Example - 
For the input = `44556841335158684945454545`
Matches are
    44
    55
    45454545
Matches should be -
45454545

How do I write a regex which excludes 44 and 55 and gives results which have different digits

Comment: Please be clear what you ask for. So what ever may be the input digits you would like to eliminate the digits 44 or 55 when they occur and display rest of the digits, am i right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To say "two different numbers repeated" you can try

```
((\d)(?!\2)\d)\1
```

Capturing parentheses are numbered from the left; so `\1` matches the entire outer pair of parentheses, and `(?!\2)` refers to the inner parentheses around the first digit, constraining the second digit so that it cannot be identical to the first.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/5f2CEf/1

Obviously, add a `+` at the end to cover all adjacent repetitions of the match.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the regex I believe you want:

```
(\d)((?!\1)\d)
```

A bit of explanation:

`(\d)`

> \d matches a digit (equal to [0-9])

`((?!\1)\d)`

> Negative Lookahead `(?!\1)`
>
> Assert that the Regex below does not match

`\1`

> matches the same text as most recently matched by the 1st capturing group

`\d`

> matches a digit (equal to [0-9])

Here is a quick JS demo:

```js
var s = "44556841335158684945454545"
console.log(s.match(/(\d)((?!\1)\d)/g))
```

Comment: This regex finds two digits which are different, not repeating groups.

Comment: I'll have to wait from more feedback from the user, but he says he wants to exclude 44 and 55 and return results that have different digits.

Comment: Triplee is right.. want to get only repeating patterns which have different digits